# How to schedule python script in google cloud without using cron jobs?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, airflow

I have two python scripts running once a day in my local environment. One is to fetch data and another is to format it.

Now I want to deploy those scripts to Google's cloud environment and run those once/twice a day.

Can I do that using Google Cloud Function or do I need App Engine?

**Why NO cron job:** Because I don't want my system/VM to run whole day (when not in use).

Can I use Cloud Composer to achieve that?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Google Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) which is a fully managed enterprise-grade cron job scheduler. It allows you to schedule virtually any job, including batch, big data jobs, cloud infrastructure operations.

The first 3 jobs per month are free. Next are $0.10 per job/month.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need App Engine and the [Cron service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) to schedule those scripts. You have some more or less straight-forward options to run those scripts on GCP:

- Deploy each one as different functions, and do something as mentioned in [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-cloud-functions-scheduling-cron-5657c2ae5212): Basically deploy a simple function in App Engine that sends an HTTP request to your(s) function(s).
- Deploy each one as different [handlers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) in App Engine, and schedule each calls.
- Deploy each one as different [services](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/microservices-on-app-engine) and then schedule the calls, bearing in mind that, if you want to schedule a call to a different service, you must specify to which one, in your `cron.yaml` file, using the `target` keyword and the name of the service.

Answer (score 0):

The information provided here: [GCP developer pro-tips](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/how-to-schedule-a-recurring-python-script-on-gcp) might be also helpful.